# How to click on the web element?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've a situation, where i need to click on element **a[data-action='remove-criteria']** when **a[data-action="edit-criteria"]** matches string..

Any help, much appreciated!!

I've included code for this..

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr scope="row">
                <td>Own publishers</td>
                <td class="input-lg">
                    <div class="label label-primary">Contained in list</div>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" data-value="22323" data-operator="list" data-attribute="pubs" data-section="supply_filter" data-action="edit-criteria" href="#">22323</a>
                    <a class="text-danger" data-value="22323" data-operator="list" data-attribute="pubs" data-section="supply_filter" data-action="remove-criteria" href="#"/>
                    <span>,</span>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" data-value="223232323" data-operator="list" data-attribute="pubs" data-section="supply_filter" **data-action="edit-criteria"** href="#">223232323</a>
                    <a class="text-danger" data-value="223232323" data-operator="list" data-attribute="pubs" data-section="supply_filter" **data-action="remove-criteria"** href="#">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `matches string`...clearly describe... and also share what have you tried??

Comment: Looking for web elements [ex: a[data-action='edit-criteria']] in a table row and if `getText()` matches '22323' then click on element a[data-action='remove-criteria'] but the problem i'm facing now is click on element a[remove-criteria] based on given string

Comment: do you mean `22323` matches to `a[data-action='remove-criteria']` elements's `data-value` attribute???

Comment: is this `xPath` valid for you `//a[@data-action = 'remove-criteria' and @data-value = '22323']` to get that link which matches provided `data-value`

Comment: yes it's valid one..

Comment: Ok then I'm converting it to answer....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `xPath` to get that link which matches provided `data-value`

```
//a[@data-action = 'remove-criteria' and @data-value = '22323']
```

Hope it will help you..:)